# Generate alphanumeric string

Tags: scala, random

I need some test company-names, like "rnd_company_blah23haf9", "rnd_company_g356fhg57" etc.

Is it possible to do something like

```
import scala.util.Random
val company = s"rnd_company_${Random.alphanumeric take 10 ?????}"
```

provided someone can fill out ????? of course.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `.mkString("")` to create a `String` from the `Stream` :

```
scala> val company = s"rnd_company_${Random.alphanumeric take 10 mkString}"
company: String = rnd_company_BbesF0EY1o
```

Comment: Sidenote: My compiler tells me to remove the unnecessary parantheses at "". So you can just write `take 10 mkString ""`.

Comment: No need in explicitly specifying empty string. Just `Random.alphanumeric take 10 mkString`

Answer (score 3):

You have an example [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/creating-random-strings-in-scala)

```
scala> val x = Random.alphanumeric
x: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Char] = Stream(Q, ?)

scala> x take 10 foreach println
Q
n
m
x
S
Q
R
e
P
B
```

So you can try this:

```
   import scala.util.Random 
   val company = s"rnd_company_${(xx take 10).mkString}"
```

Comment: That was exactly the example I started with. There is something missing in your code (Random.*)?

Comment: I forgot to add it to the example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something verbose than the above answers but this one helps you to constrain the alphabet:

```
def randomText(textLength: Int = 10, alphabet: List[Char] = ('a' to 'd').toList) = {
    (1 to textLength).toList.map { charPos =>
        val randomIndex = (Math.random() * alphabet.length).floor.toInt
        alphabet(randomIndex)
    }.mkString("")
}
```